# MySQL-Workbench starts and "Icon not found: sidebar_wb.png"

Tags: linux, debian, mysql-workbench

```
(mysql-workbench-bin:10341): glibmm-ERROR **:
unhandled exception (type std::exception) in signal handler:
what: Icon not found: sidebar_wb.png

Trace/breakpoint trap
```

Comment: Sounds like you have a corrupt installation. Try reinstalling the package. Make sure you get the full package from http.//dev.mysql.com.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is Reinstall WorkBench,Following link contains the solution

[Visit the MySQL Bugs](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79224)